# how to write to java file in the best way

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I wrote a java code to write a file in a known pattern(in order to use later regex for the reading). Is there a better way to write the code? (I am trying to improve my coding).

```
public void writeRecipe(Recipe r)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file = new File(r.getPath());
    try {
        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bufferwirte = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
        filewriter.append(r.getType() + " Recipe:" + "\t"  + r.getName() +"\n");
        filewriter.append("\t" + "Ingredients List:\n");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : r.getIngredients().entrySet())
        {
            filewriter.append(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue() + "\n");

        }
        filewriter.append("\n\tDirections:\n" );
        for(String dir :r.getDirections())
        {
            filewriter.append(dir + "\n");
        }
        bufferwirte.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.err.println("WritingFileRecipeErr: " + e );
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and maybe even [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)

Comment: Why not `Serialize` the `Object`, that way you don't have to parse it (and regex isn't usually the best idea for implementing a parser).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Don't get me started on Serialization for the long term storage of objects...Better to use JAXB or even a JSON parser :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer what class to import if I want to use JSON parser that is build in java ?

Comment: @RonAham You'll have to use a third party parser, GSON is popular, I've used [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) which isn't bad

Comment: Depending on for what reason you store the data into a file the format and technique might be chosen.

Comment: @swinkler I want to create a program that write and read from recipes files like a cookbook class, but I do want the files to be readable. what format do you think will work best?

Comment: @RonAham JSON is considered to be easy readable. XML sounds like a bit too much for what you need but also would work fine.